# Two events in a single element [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

(Sorry for the bad english hahah) I have a span with 'glyphicon-chevron-down' icon, when i click on it, it should show some informations and change the icon to 'glyphicon-chevron-up', and it works fine. So now, my span has the class 'down' removed and I added the 'up' class, ok. But i need another event, for when the user clicks on 'glyphicon-chevron-up', this event should make the reverse of previous (follows the code and the page print):

**PHP Code:**

```
echo "<li class='folder list-group-item' id=\"".$folder['Folder']['folder_id']."\">".$space."
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open'></span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$folder['Folder']['name']."
      <a href='#'><span name='rotate' class='pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'>
      </span></a><br>";
```

**JQuery Code:**

```js
$(".subfile").hide();

$(".glyphicon-chevron-down").on("click", function(){
  parents = $(this).parents('li:first');
  $(parents).siblings('li').fadeIn();
  $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  $(this).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
});

$(".glyphicon-chevron-up").on("click", function(){
  parents = $(this).parents('li:first');
  $(parents).siblings('li').fadeOut();
  $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  $(this).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
});
```

**Page prints:**

[(The page starts this way)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qCsU.jpg)

[(When click in the 'up' icon, should back to previous state)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOaNK.jpg)

If needs some more information, please ask on comments and I will put here! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

use `toggleClass()` and `fadeToggle()` instead:

```
$(".glyphicon-chevron-down").on("click", function(){
  parents = $(this).parents('li:first');
  $(parents).siblings('li').fadeToggle(); // fadeToggle
  $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

a sample test case:

```js
$(".down").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('down up');
  $(this).siblings('p').fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
.down {color: red;}
.up {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='down'>up-down</button>
<p>fade it toggle too.</p>
```

Comment: I tried, the icon changes ok, but when i click on 'up' the subfile keeps showing, where can i change this? (thanks a lot for the help!!)

Comment: the subfile is outside of this click event that have to be in it.